# CSS transform:rotateX for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, transform, parallax

I'm making a website ([Parallax web page](http://www.sbplanet.co/)) that has parallax elements in it. Right now the parallax part seems to work fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE.
There is the 'js/forest_unfixed.js' that applies calculations on the not working `id="cont-3d"` div. I'm trying to do

```
cont3d.style["-ms-transform"] = "rotateX("+(90+(dyn_ratio)*(yPos/maxy))+"deg)";
cont3d.style.transform = "rotateX("+(90+(dyn_ratio)*(yPos/maxy))+"deg)";
```

I also tried using Modernizr, but it's the very same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `cont3d.style["msTransform"]`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work either

Comment: IE 11, is latest one I think

Comment: Just so you know; IE11 doesn't require prefixing for the `transform` property. Having said that, try `cont3d.style.msTransform`.

Comment: Oh that's really good to know. Unfortunately it still doesn't work (I left the code like you suggested so you can check, @Shaggy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem there could be that IE doesn't play nice with nested 3d elements. Take a look at this answer:

[CSS3 3D Transform doesn't work on IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848328/css3-3d-transform-dont-work-on-ie11)