# css hover on IE11

Tags: javascript, css, html

first see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahendrakulkarni/427wpekf/1/) code,

On `hover` any div, it will flip, after fliping `back side text and style` not showing on `IE 11`

*Please check on **chrome or Firefox** its working fine*

Comment: It is very buggy in chrome also

Comment: [IE does not support the transform-style: perserve-3d property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d). Similar question perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848328/css3-3d-transform-dont-work-on-ie11

Comment: `#one:hover` to `#eight:hover` - all have the same CSS code, why are you using these selectors separately? You can club them in single. Also you can combine same styles from `#one` to `#eight` into single class and use that class. It would be easier to maintain CSS.

Comment: You need to have code when linking a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Apply rotation not to the parent but to the front and back panels themselves. For this create a front panel, you have only a back one at the moment:

```
<div id="one">
    <div class="front face">
      <h3 class="text">Developer</h3>
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
    </div>        
    <div class="back face center">
        <p>one Back Side</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each panel has backface-visibility:hidden

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/427wpekf/3/)**

P.S. didn't understand why you need preserve-3d...