# preserve-3d for transformation failed on IE

Tags: javascript, css

https://codepen.io/collosic/pen/KsfwD

```
<td ng-repeat="card in row.cards" class="ng-scope">
                <div class="card_container " ng-click="isGuarding || check(card)">
                  <div class="card shadow">
                    <div class="front face"></div>
                    <div class="back face text-center pagination-center">
                      <p class="ng-binding"> 3 </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
```

Sad this doesn't work in IE at all. When clicked, it shows white background.

Comment: So your question is? How to make it work in IE? Which version?

Comment: the 3d transformations are not supported in IE below edge or partially 11 . see here http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d or here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-style.asp

Comment: @SteffenHarbich 9 and above

Comment: @MihaiT so it's not possible to make flip work in IE? I've seen working version demo

Comment: it is possible . read the top answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848328/css3-3d-transform-dont-work-on-ie11 or search other similar questions here on stackoverflow. there are many of them

Comment: @MihaiT still can't make it work. maybe the stucture is different.